# ¿Cómo crear un ".deb" o un "tar.gz" o un ".sh"?

Tags: linux, debian, compilar

mi pregunta es como puedo crear un paquete .deb para la distro debian, así como en windows se compila y se crea un archivo ".exe", quiero saber como crear un archivo .deb para debian

Comment: ¡Muchas preguntas en una sola!. Crear un ejecutable para linux, en cualquiera de sus distribuciones, no es tan distinto de crear un ejecutable para  Windows. Necesitas un compilador capaz de emitir ejecutables linux y simplemente compilar tu código fuente. ¿En qué lenguaje?, bueno, hay variedad, c, c++, pascal y muchos otros tienen disponibilidad de compiladores para linux. No confundas eso con un `.sh`, que sería más o menos equivalente a un `.bat`, que es una secuencia de comandos para el interprete (en este caso `bash`), un `tar.gz` que es un archivo comprimido.

Comment: digamos que equivalente a un `.zip` (aunque no exactamente igual), o un `.deb` que es un paquete de instalación, que puede contener uno o varios ejecutables, para debian (o ubuntú y otros derivados de debian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Resumen rápido.

1. Crea un ejecutable: compílalo, haz un `.sh` y dale permisos de ejecución, lo que sea.
2. Crea un árbol de directorios, en la carpeta en que te encuentras, de la siguiente manera.

   ```
   usr/
    |___ local/
           |_____ bin/
   ```

   Si quieres puedes poner la página del manual en `usr/share/man/man1/`
3. Mueve ese ejecutable que creaste a `usr/local/bin/`
4. Haz un archivo `tar` o `gz` de la carpeta `usr/` que creaste en tu directorio de trabajo.
5. Usa el programa `alien` con los parámetros `--to-deb` y `<el archivo tar o gz>`
6. Instala el archivo `.deb`, que generó `alien`, con `dpkg -i <el archivo .deb>`
7. Escribe el nombre del programa.

#### Ejemplo práctico.

Esto hazlo dentro de una carpeta específica para este ejercicio, porque vas a crear varios archivos y carpetas.

Paso 1.

Voy a hacer un script en bash rápido.

Escribe en tu consola lo siguiente (copia y pega)

```
echo '#!/bin/bash
echo Hola, wey, parse, wn, che, tío, po, pe, aweoneao. Este es $(basename $0)' > nuevo_programa
chmod +x nuevo_programa
```

Paso 2.

```
mkdir -p usr/local/bin
```

Paso 3.

```
mv nuevo_programa usr/local/bin/
```

Paso 4.

```
tar czf nuevo_programa.tar usr
```

Paso 5.

```
sudo alien --to-deb nuevo_programa.tar  # Si no tienes alien, instalalo con sudo apt install alien
```

En la carpeta donde estás trabajando se va a crear un archivo `.deb`, algo así como un  `nuevo-programa_1-2_all.deb`

Paso 6.

```
sudo dpkg -i nuevo-programa_1-2_all.deb  # Suponiendo que el archivo .deb se llama asi.
```

Paso 7.

```
nuevo_programa
Hola, wey, parse, wn, che, tío, po, pe, aweoneao. Este es nuevo_programa
```

Si quieres eliminarlo, simplemente escribe.

```
sudo dpkg -r nuevo-programa
```

#### Nota chistosa.

Si te das cuenta, para crear este archivo `.deb`, creaste tanto un script de shell como un `tar` o `gz`. Así que usamos todo lo que preguntabas para un pequeño proyecto.

### Otra manera

Otra manera que conozco, pero que no involucra un archivo `tar` o `gz`, es la que creo que es la "formal". Gran parte la puedes ver [aquí](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=910717).

1. Creamos tu carpeta con el nombre de tu paquete con la siguiente sintaxis `nombre-paquete.<mayor>.<minor>-<revision>`

   ```
   mkdir programa-prueba.1.0-1
   ```
2. Creamos el árbol que consideres conveniente haciendo de cuenta que esa nueva carpeta que creaste es la carpeta raíz. En este caso, la documentación de `hier(7)` establece que `/usr/local/bin` es el lugar ideal para poner ejecutables locales a tu computadora, servidor, sitio, etc. Entonces crearemos esa carpeta.

   ```
   mkdir -p programa-prueba.1.0-1/usr/local/bin
   ```
3. Creamos un ejecutable, y si ya lo tienes, lo movemos o copiamos a esa carpeta.

   ```
   echo '#!/bin/bash
   echo Hola, wey, parse, wn, che, tío, po, pe, aweoneao. Este es $(basename $0)' > programa-prueba
   chmod +x programa-prueba
   mv programa-prueba programa-prueba.1.0-1/usr/local/bin/
   ```
4. Como vamos a utilizar `dpkg-deb`, en su manual ,`dpkg-deb(1)`, se establece, en la opción de `-b`, que el directorio debe de tener un subdirectorio llamado `DEBIAN`, el cual contiene los archivos de control de información. Así que lo creamos.

   ```
   mkdir programa-prueba.1.0-1/DEBIAN
   ```
5. Dentro de esa carpeta hay un archivo de control importante que es el archivo `control`, lo editamos con `vim programa-prueba.1.0-1/DEBIAN/control` y tiene que tener algo por el estilo.

   ```
   Package: programa-prueba
   Version: 1.0-1
   Section: base
   Priority: optional
   Architecture: all
   Maintainer: Marco <mi_correo@gmail.com>
   Description: Descripcion de programa prueba
       Aqui va la descripcion
   ```

   El formato y opciones de este archivo lo puedes consultar en `deb-control(5)` con `man 5 deb-control`.
6. Cambias los permisos y el propietario del árbol.

   ```
   sudo chown -R root:root programa-prueba.1.0-1  # Cambialo al usuario que quieras, aunque a veces te puedes saltar este paso.
   sudo chmod -R 0755 programa-prueba.1.0-1  # Esto es necesario, sino, dpkg-deb no te permitira
                                             # instalarlo por los permisos de la carpeta de control "DEBIAN".
   ```
7. Creas el archivo `.deb`

   ```
   sudo dpkg-deb -b programa-prueba.1.0-1
   ```
8. (opcional) Dentro del directorio en el que te encuentras se encuentra el nuevo archivo `.deb` creado. Para ver la información que pusiste en el archivo `control` sólo escribe `sudo dpkg -I programa-prueba.1.0-1.deb` y verás los datos que escribiste en el archivo "control".
9. Instala el paquete `.deb`

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i programa-prueba.1.0-1.deb
   ```
10. Ya lo puedes correr con

    ```
    $ programa-prueba
    Hola, wey, parse, wn, che, tío, po, pe, aweoneao. Este es programa-prueba
    ```

Como puedes ver, gran parte de esto lo puedes automatizar con un buen script.